# Data arrangement

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, python, perl

I have data which i would like get output in below format using shell/perl script.

Data:

```
Virtual Machine  Test status  Running.
Assigned Server  OVS001.local
Virtual Disk  Test_DISK1 (30) size  61GB
Physical Disk  HITACHI (110)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (113)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (111)
```

Required Output:

```
Virtual_Machine    Vdsks               size     Physical_Disks
Test               Test_DISK1          61GB        -
Test                 -                  -        HITACHI (110)
Test                 -                  -        HITACHI (113)
Test                 -                  -        HITACHI (111)
```

This needs to be pulled for multiple vm's..

Comment: Doing such formatting is easiest with some scripting language, like Perl or Python

Comment: Jason i got this script but its not helping me out..

Script for your reference:http://pastie.org/10711689

Output: [root@ovmtest ~]# ./invgen2.sh < /tmp/Automated/Virtualmachines_DETAILS.txt
Virtual_Machine    Vdsks               size     Physical_Disks
[root@ovmtx ~]#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`perl` was designed and made for precisely this kind of problem. It's nickname was "pathological eclectic rubbish lister".

Read the documentation on [perlform](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html). What you do is read your data (say, line at a time), parse it, stuff into variables, then issue the command `write` which outputs the current data based on a `format` which you defined.

For your data you might have a format for the header:

```
format STDOUT_TOP = 
Virtual_Machine    Vdsks               size      Physical_Disks
-----------------  ------------------  --------- ---------------
.
```

and another for each line of output:

```
format STDOUT = 
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  @>>>>>>>>>>> -
$virtualmachine,   @vdisk,             @vdisk_size
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<~~  @>>>>>>>>>~~ -
$#vdisk<0?'':$virtualmachine,   shift(@vdisk), shift(@vdisk_size)
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  -                                ^<<<<<<<<<<<<~~
$#disks<0?'':$virtualmachine,                       shift(@disks)

.
```

I'm not sure how you get your data, but let's say you have it in one file separated by two newlines. Each host is a block of lines:

```
Virtual Machine  Test1 status  Running.
Assigned Server  OVS001.local
Virtual Disk  Test_DISK1 (30) size  61GB
Physical Disk  HITACHI (110)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (113)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (111)

Virtual Machine  Test status  Running.
Assigned Server  OVS002.local
Virtual Disk  Test_DISK1 (30) size  41GB
Physical Disk  HITACHI (110)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (113)
Physical Disk  HITACHI (111)
```

You set your input-delimiter character like this:

```
$/="\n\n";
```

Every time you read, you're getting a whole block of text, ie, all the lines for one virtual host.

```
while (<>) { 
    # process one virtual machine
}
```

Now the fun begins: parsing the input. Inside the while loop, you might do this:

```
my @lines=split("\n");
local @disks=(); # initialize
local $virtualmachine="unknown";
local $physicalserver="unknown";
local @vdisk=("unknown");
local @vdisk_size=("unknown");
foreach (@lines) { 
    $virtualmachine = $1 if /^Virtual Machine\s+(\S+)\s+status\s+/;
    $physicalserver = $1 if /^Assigned Server\s+(\S+)/;
    do { push @vdisk,$1; push @vdisk_size,$2; }
       if /^Virtual Disk\s+(\S+).* size\s+(\d+\w+)/;
    push @disks,$1 if /^Physical Disk\s+(.*)/;
}
write;
```

The parsing is crude, but usually effective.

Comment: Thanks for your response Otheus, I am totally new to the perl scripting so could you please help me to sort this out..

I tried executing this script but looks like iam missing something..
 For your reference :http://pastie.org/10711686

Comment: Updated pastie. http://pastie.org/10711947  Three mistakes: (1) you left out the header to tell UNIX it must run perl for this script, (2) the `format` keyword and `.` (both times), (3) the parsing code goes inside the while loop.

Comment: It worked like a charm..The only problem i see is the virtual machine name is not getting repeated for each physical/Virtual disks. Please find below the o/p
http://pastie.org/10711953

Comment: Why would you want that??  OK, I edited the answer with 3 lines in the `format` section. I didn't put that there first because the code is a bit tricky and not very clear. The "obvious" way of doing it won't work because of special rules regarding the `~~` at the end of the disk-picture field.

Comment: Actually those Hitachi disks are being shared with other vm's as well..so having vm's name in each line would help to sort out the list of virtual machine with which its being shared

Comment: @biz I see. In that case, see the latest change -- where the physical disk is NOT rpeorted on the first line . And upvote/accept when you can

Comment: After doing little adjument in the spacing the new script looks perfectly fine apart from one issue..Say for example if my virtual machine has 2 or more vdisks the output just shows one disk though for physical disk o/p it looks good..Please find below the pasty output..http://pastie.org/10712113

Comment: The principle is the same but you'll have to modify $vdisk and $vdisk_size to become arrays (`@vdisk` instead of `$vdisk`).

Comment: @biz check answer again. Look at edit history or diffs to see and understand the principle.

Comment: The output looks good the only issue is the unknown errors..http://pastie.org/10712293

Comment: If you can just help me in excluding those unknown errors.. I am almost done with generating the report..Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: That's a vestige from the previous version. Just remove "unknown" from the list initializatins. (Where I changed from scalar to list). Sorry, I can't edit code from iPad

Answer (score 0):

Depends how precisely you want the formatting - usually tab separated is enough - but I'd tackle it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#set record separator to double line feed.     
local $/ = "\n\n";

#print header row
print join "\t", "VM", "Virtual_Disk", "size", "Physical Disks", "\n";

#iterate stdin or files specified on command line
while ( <> ) { 
   #capture data from this 'chunk':
   my ( $vm ) = /Virtual Machine\s+(\w+)/;   
   my ( $status ) = /status\s*(\w+)/; 
   my @physical_disks = m/Physical Disk\s+(.*)/g; 
   my %virtual_disks = m/Virtual Disk\s+(\w+).*size\s+(\w+)/g;

   #output tab separated
   print join ("\t", $vm, $_, $virtual_disks{$_}, "-" ), "\n" for keys %virtual_disks;
   print join ("\t", $vm, "-", "-", $_ ), "\n" for @physical_disks;   
}
```

This aligns to tab stops, rather than fixed width per se. This may be more suitable, depending on your use case. Otherwise - you can either use `format` as outlined above, or `sprintf` to fix the field width:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "\n\n";
my $field_format = "%8s";  #string, 8 chars wide

print join "\t", map { sprintf $field_format, $_ } "VM", "Virtual_Disk", "size", "Physical Disks", "\n";

while ( <> ) { 
   my ( $vm ) = /Virtual Machine\s+(\w+)/;   
   my ( $status ) = /status\s*(\w+)/; 
   my @physical_disks = m/Physical Disk\s+(.*)/g; 
   my %virtual_disks = m/Virtual Disk\s+(\w+).*size\s+(\w+)/g;
   print join "\t", map { sprintf $field_format, $_} ( $vm, $_, $virtual_disks{$_}, "-" ), "\n" for keys %virtual_disks;
   print join "\t", map { sprintf $field_format, $_} ( $vm, "-", "-", $_ ), "\n" for @physical_disks;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sobrique, The only issue what i see with second script is the spacing issue for the physical disk column..http://pastie.org/10712313

Comment: Change that 08 to a bigger number, or reduce the length of the column heading.